# Automatically create pages in a post based on number of words

Tags: posts, pagination, pages

I need a method to automatically create pages (using `<!--nextpage-->`) in posts based on number of words.

For example... A post containing 1200 words should be broken down into 6 pages with page break coming after every 200 words.

I understand that I can do it manually. But this functionality is needed for a site powered by WordPress that would contain archives of imported data in multiple languages.

Tried searching for a plugin that would accomplish something like this. Could not find it.

Answer (score 4):

This is tough to do programmatically because of potential variations in html and how the tags balance. However, if you were to try, here's how I'd suggest doing it.

First of all, WordPress sets up the post pagination in `setup_postdata()`, which is called at the end of `the_post()`. That means you need to get those `<!--nextpage-->` lines in the posts before the end of `the_post()`. The `'loop_start'` action should work for those purposes. It even passes a copy of the current WP_Query object by reference, so you can make changes directly to the queried posts!

Something like this is a start:

```
add_action( 'loop_start', 'wpse14677_loop_start' );

function wpse14677_loop_start( $query ) {
    foreach( $query->posts as $index => $post ) {
        $words = preg_split( '/ +/', $post->post_content, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );
        $pages = array();
        while ( $words ) {
            $word_count = count ( $words );
            if ( 200 >= $word_count ) {
                $pages[] = implode( ' ', $words );
                $words = array();
            } else {
                $pages[] = implode( ' ', array_slice( $words, 0, 200 ) );
                $words = array_slice( $words, 200 );
            }
        }
        $page_count = count( $pages );
        if( 1 < $page_count ) {
            $query->posts[ $index ]->post_content = implode( "\n<!--nextpage-->\n", $pages );
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully that gives you an idea of what you would need to do. I'd suggest finding some way of temporarily stripping html tags and replacing them after inserting the `nextpage` flags, because the function above will also count spaces inside HTML tags, and could even put a page break inside one.

Comment: nice! +1. The only thing i'd change would be to set the `count($words)` before the if statement (faster).

Comment: total novice here guys. can you tell me where do i place this code? in functions.php file in the template directory?

Comment: Functions.php should do just right, but as I said, this right now will cause some very eratic behavior if there's a lot of html in your posts. I'll update the answer if I think of a good way to fix that problem.

Comment: @kaiser wrt to your comment above, can you please add an answer or edit the existing one? (whichever is appropriate) It would be very helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for saving my time. While migrating non wordpress site in to wordpress i was trying to replace **PAGEBREAK** in to wordpress  I have done this with following syntax.

```
function make_pagebreak_nextpaglink( $query  ) {
   foreach( $query->posts as $index => $post ) {
      $content = str_replace('__PAGEBREAK__', '<!--nextpage-->',   $post->post_content);
      $query->posts[ $index ]->post_content = $content;
   }
}
add_action('loop_start', 'make_pagebreak_nextpaglink');
```

Answer (score -1):

Studio Hyperset's Page-Links Plus "auto pagination" module can help you accomplish this.

It allows WordPress users to trade tedious in-line  tags for a site-wide management tool that paginates posts and pages quickly and uniformly.

The module automatically prevents widows, orphans, trailing headers, and avoids splitting sentences and individual words and can be configured to override or ignore existing in-line  tags.

Check it out here: http://pagelinksplus.com/wordpress-pagination-modules/wordpress-pagination-auto-pagination

Comment: Welcome to WPSE Quimby! Please ensure you disclose any affiliation with plug-ins you refer to. Also, please [read this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) - some might consider this post bordering between advert and answer :).