# Paginate the_content automatically?

Tags: pagination, the-content

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically create pages in a post based on number of words](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14677/automatically-create-pages-in-a-post-based-on-number-of-words)

Can Wordpress automatically paginate large amounts of content?

A user wants to enter a document that is 3000 words long. They just want to paste this into `the_content` via the cms. Can Wordpress then automatically paginate that into separate pages that are say 300 words long?

Or would it have to be done manually? Where they separate the content into 10 separate pages?

Comment: Version 1.1 of [Autopaginate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/autopaginate/) plugin is said to be working with the latest versions of WordPress — http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/autopaginate/tags/1.1/

Answer (score 1):

Use the `<!--nextpage-->` tag

http://codex.wordpress.org/Write_Post_SubPanel#Quicktags

> can be used any number of times in a post, and each insert will "break" and paginate the post at that location. Hyperlinks to the paginated sections of the post are then generated in combination with the wp_link_pages() or link_pages() template tag.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know that! Although that's still a manual process.